# Divide result of query depends of the data

Tags: php, sql, informix

When I get information from the Informix database, it gives me about 4500 rows and it has different `codi_zona`. So I make this query to give me in the data in order:

```
select nomb_terc, dire_refe, codi_zona, nuev_terr
  from x9
 order by codi_zona asc;
```

Output Data 1
[image: example data from database]

But I want to get that information in desorder without losing the order of the `codi_zona` column:Other Output Data 2

```
nomb_terc ! dire_refe ! codi_zona  ! nuev_terr
ALAN      ! AS        !   001      ! 25
ALF       ! AS        !   001      ! 22
MARIA     ! AS        !   001      ! 21
RENZO     ! AS        !   004      ! 15
RENATO    ! AS        !   004      ! 145
JUAN      ! AS        !   004      ! 12
CHRIS     ! AS        !   004      ! 25
JILL      ! AS        !   015      ! 15
CLAIRE    ! AS        !   015      ! 13
LEON      ! AS        !   015      ! 25
TEDDY     ! AS        !   003      ! 11
ADA       ! AS        !   003      ! 8
SOFIA     ! AS        !   003      ! 25
```

Please help me with that problem. Is there any query to help me to get the kind of data explained in the example?

Comment: I wonder if anyone has a clue of what you are asking.

Comment: @toral-clases-de-coreano Please share sample data for all 3 people (Pepito ,Carlos , Martin ). Your sample data and explanation are not too clear.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on the Spanish StackOverflow — https://es.stackoverflow.com/ — because it is rather difficult to work out what you're asking.  (I'm guessing based on Google's analysis of your name as Spanish.)  Failing that, you need to show enough data for us to be able to produce the output you seek from the data you show, without needing too much data.  It is not clear where division comes into the picture yet.

Comment: Thank for your replay , I change my question @JonathanLeffler , So can you understand me now ?

Comment: You show two table fragments; there doesn't seem to be any correlation between the data in them, though the column names match.  It isn't clear, therefore, whether those fragments are both input data, or one is input and the other the desired output.  Please make sure you include input data — a representation of a fragment of the table you are selecting from — and the output data that you want, and an explanation of how the input and output are related.  At this stage, I'm still bemused; I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Hi @JonathanLeffler ,To tell the true both are ouput data . the pic show the first output data that i get from database and it gives me in order  because of clause " order by codi_zona asc" , the important column here is codi_zona because i want to agrupate depends codi_zona column.  the other output data is that i want to get.The query  give me the information.with that data i want to make another query to give me randomly data agrupate by codi_zona like the second output.

Comment: OK; please update the question to explain this.  Also provide sample input data for at least one, possibly both, of the sets of output data.  On the whole, I think you should only show one lot of desired output and a sufficient subset of the input data to produce that output data.  Without both, it is hard to work out what the mapping should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is to sort the results of your query in a particular way based on the contents of the codi_zona column.

While I don't believe there's a standard way to do this, different databases may offer different options. If you happen to be using MySql you can probably achieve this by using [ORDER BY FIELD](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/) as per below:

```
SELECT codi_zona, nomb_empl, apel_empl, direction FROM x8 
ORDER BY FIELD(codi_zona, 1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Hi thank for your answer.i am using informix. , just want to change the order based on the contents of codi_zona column like random. not that way codi_zona 1,2,3 .. I mean codi_zona 1,1,1,1,1 then 10,10,10,10 then 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 then 5,5,5,5,5, and i have a lot of codi_zona for about 100 and it need to change radomly, so i cant make one by one. because i dont know if the next data come the same codi_zona.thx in advance.